# System.Windows.Browser in Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, browser, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to open a webpage in a Silverlight App for Windows Phone 7.

Is there a way to open Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to use the WebBrowser Task to open a WebPage in Internet Explorer.
Add the following using statement:

`using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;`

Then you can use the Task in a function such as below:

`WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask();

task.URL = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";

task.Show();`

Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem, when I first wanted to do this it took me a while to find an example!

Comment: thanks man, searching for "WP7 open browser" is about as un-google-able as they come

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser(VS.92).aspx) in your app to [open local HTML content](https://web.archive.org/web/20160307035155/http://jeffblankenburg.com/post/31-days-of-windows-phone-7c-day-18-webbrowser-control.aspx) or [open a website](https://web.archive.org/web/20150924230051/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/dohollan/archive/2010/08/25/adventures-with-the-windows-phone-7-webbrowser-control.aspx). [Here is an articl](https://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/windows-phone-7-development-using-webbrowser-control)e that shows you how to load content into the WebBrowser control. if you need to style the content in the WebBrowser control, check [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150228122351/http://www.ben.geek.nz:80/2010/07/integrated-links-and-styling-for-windows-phone-7-webbrowser-control/) and [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150123022000/http://www.ben.geek.nz/2010/06/displaying-html-strings-in-the-windows-phone-7-webbrowser/).